# SQLAlchemy insert a record with ForeignKey, why the ForeignKey auto increase?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import event

Base = declarative_base()

class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'employee'
    sid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    type = Column(String(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'employee',
        'polymorphic_on':type
    }

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = 'manager'
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('employee.sid'), primary_key=True)
    manager_name = Column(String(30))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'manager',
    }

e = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/test?charset=utf8', echo=False)
Base.metadata.create_all(e)

s = Session(e)

b=Manager()
b.id=101
b.name="manager"
b.manager_name="jack"

s.add(b)

s.commit()
```

this code run first time, result is below:

```
---table employee---
sid, name, type
1 manager manager
---table manager---
id, manager_name
1   jack
I think the id and Sid should be 101
```

this code run second times, result is below:

```
---table employee---
sid, name, type
1 manager manager
2 manager manager
---table manager---
id, manager_name
1   jack
2   jack
```

I think it should insert row failed. Because the employee table has the sid with 101 , can't insert same Sid record. Instead, the record inserted with sid value 1. Run the code again, insert a new record with sid value 2.

Why the result like this?

Comment: yeah,Employee 's sid auto increase by default.But I set id for manager, this id should be the value that I setted. Dimmed :(

Comment: Well, a simple solution is to set the `sid` attribute, which is the primary key of the parent table, instead of the `id`, so that it's not auto generated.

Comment: yeah, change the ORM generated table employee ,set sid not auto increment. If manager instance b does't set sid attribute, this script will get error msg "Field 'sid' doesn't have a default value". So I think it should be a bug for sqlalchemy.

Comment: No, I meant that instead of `b.id = 101` do `b.sid = 101`. Don't go changing anything. That's not a bug. You cannot have a primary key without a default and not give it a value.

Comment: yes. just add  b.sid = 101. It's go well. Thanks very much. but I think sqlalchemy should set b.sid self, no I should explicit do it.

Comment: But, that's exactly what it does, if you do not explicitly override it. I fail to understand what is the problem. In fact it protected you from trying to break your referential integrity in that it does not allow you to explicitly override the *foreign key*, while the primary key of the parent table is auto generated. Depending on the DB in use it would also scream.

Comment: Thanks llja. You think sqlalchemy protected my program to break. In my option, It save the value not I wanted. It's hard to explain for sqlalchemy beginner. After our talks, I got more detail for sqlalchemy. :)